# How to collect return value of onbeforeunload

Tags: javascript, dom-events, onbeforeunload

I am displaying a warning message if user try to close window without saving the form.

```
window.onbeforeunload = askConfirm;

    function askConfirm()
    {
        // needToConfirm is set to true if any changes are there in the form
        if (needToConfirm)
        {
            return "Your unsaved data will be lost.";
        }       
    } 

    function call_this_if_user_clicks_on_cancel()
    {
       // Bla bla bla
       // After this user should remain on the same page.
    }
```

Now I want to call another function when user clicks on `Okay`. And rest of the functionality should remain same. 
So how can I collect `onbeforeunload` return value and call another function ?

**SOLUTION:**

```
    needToConfirm = false; 
    window.onbeforeunload = askConfirm;
    window.onunload = unloadPage;
    isDelete = true;

    function unloadPage()
    {
        if(isDelete)
        {
           call_this_if_user_clicks_on_cancel() 
        }   
    }

    function askConfirm()
    {
        alert("onbeforeunload");
        if (needToConfirm)
        {
            // Message to be displayed in Warning.
            return "Your data will be lost.";
        } 
        else
        {
            isDelete = false;
        }   
    }
```

Comment: You mean you want to have "secondary" `onbeforeunload`?

Comment: I think you can call the function instead of return in your code and pass the string. If I understand your question correctly.

Comment: @Shadow: I want to execute some steps if user clicks on `Cancel` and rest of the thing should be the same as default

Comment: @Felix: Ya it seems but is there any work around ?

Comment: @Asad: Ya kind of. It will be great if you can provide some details.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I'm not certain; But I would of thought you cannot call another function, as a preventative measure by the browser so it doesn't get trapped from leaving the page.

I think only the browser knows if it's returns true / false to determine if the page is unloaded (or not).

Previously unbeforeunload was non-standard (from IE4, but supported by other browsers)
Here are the Mozilla docs https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.onbeforeunload
And Microsoft docs: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms536907(VS.85).aspx

However it looks as thought BeforeUnloadEvent is in the HTML5 proposal.
This document gives in detail the steps that happen when a document is unloaded (interesting read):

http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/history.html#beforeunloadevent

---

As a workaround:
You may be able to gather the information you need from the "unload event", if the unload event is NOT called after the onbeforeunload, you could assume that the user chose to stay on your page.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.onunload

Comment: @Alex: Thanks man.This is what exactly I wanted. Now it don't sound impossible.

Comment: @Ajinkya: No worries glad to be of assistance, I'd be interested to see how you get along. Drop a comment on here if you get a sec if this works out ok for you.

Comment: @Alex:Its working but `onunload ` is called whenever I click on any other link.

Comment: @Ajinkya: yeah, onbeforeunload and onunload will both be called on anything that causes the document to unload i.e. navigate somewhere else. If you need it on only certain links, you could perhaps attach the event within the click event (e.g. so attaching it just before you unload).

Comment: @Alex: I tried some ad hoc solution.I have updates my question with solution.