# how to use window.onbeforeunload?

Tags: javascript, onbeforeunload

I have a small webpage. i need to activate my ajax function when browser is closed

I using below JavaScript for that in the `<head>`

```
<script language="JavaScript" type="text/javascript">
 window.onbeforeunload = confirmExit;
  function confirmExit()
  {    
    my ajax_function();
    return "";
  }
</script>
```

But this function works all in the **Back button, Forward button, ALT+f5, CTL+f5, Submit etc...** But i need this function only when browser is closed

But i try like below in my webpage to block the events like **Back button, Forward button, ALT+f5, CTL+f5, Submit** etc...

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function () { 

$('a').click(function(){window.onbeforeunload = null;});
$(window).keydown(function(event) { 
  if (event.keyCode == 116) { // User presses F5 to refresh
     window.onbeforeunload = null;
   }});
$('form').submit(function() {

   window.onbeforeunload = null;
});

});

</script>
```

But this only for hyperlink, refresh, and submit.

What i need is, `window.onbeforeunload` function only works `when browser is closed`

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6579509/how-to-collect-return-value-of-onbeforeunload

Comment: Using `onbeforeunload` is normally a sign of bad practice. If I were you take a look at your code and try to rewrite it without having to use a `onbeforeunload`/any exit specific code.

Answer (score 0):

JavaScript doesn't distinguish between these events, they are all triggered because the user is leaving the page.

Comment: There is any other solution to activate my ajax_function when browser/tab close